# Receiving data from a serial port using ReadAsync

Tags: c#, .net-core, stream, serial-port

I'm trying to communicate with a piece of hardware over a serial port and I've noticed that it's quite tricky. After reading up on some of the `SerialPort` caveats, I discovered [this post by Ben Voigt](https://www.sparxeng.com/blog/software/must-use-net-system-io-ports-serialport) on alternative approaches to handle serial communication in .NET with the `SerialPort` class.

However, this code is quite old (8 years or so as of today) and the `Stream` class now exposes asynchronous read/write support, so I was wondering how the code in that blog could be re-written to account for the following scenarios:

1. The device periodically sends a status update through the port (auto generated)
2. I can send a byte array that represents a command that doesn't need a response
3. I can send a byte array that represents a command that *does* need a response, and the device will send that reply data through the port

So far, I have a simple read loop that looks a bit like this:

```cs
public async IAsyncEnumerable<byte> ReadBytesAsync()
{
  while (_port.IsOpen)
  {
    byte[]? buffer = new byte[1];
    try
    {
      await _port.BaseStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, 1);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      // Do stuff
    }
    if (buffer is not null) yield return buffer[0];
    await Task.Delay(1); // Wait a bit before reading again
  }
}
```

I also have a `GetRepliesAsync()` method that `await foreach`es over the read bytes and constructs the right data types for the replies.

The autogenerated status update gets read correctly when received, but if I use `_port.BaseStream.WriteAsync(commandBytes, 0, commandBytes.Length)`, the device receives the update but I somehow don't receive its reply through the base stream.

What could I be doing wrong, and how can I actually read the received bytes?

### UPDATES

#### 1. Modified read and added delay

I got the code to work somewhat with the following approach:

```cs
while (_port.IsOpen)
{
    if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested) yield break;
    
    int bufferLength = 2048; // Arbitrary buffer length
    byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferLength];
    try
    {
        // Partially using Ben Voigt's approach
        int bytesRead = await _port.BaseStream
            .ReadAsync(buffer.AsMemory(0, bufferLength), cancellationToken);
        nextBytes = new byte[bytesRead];
        Buffer.BlockCopy(buffer, 0, nextBytes, 0, bytesRead);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        Console.WriteLine("Terminating serial read polling...");
        yield break;
    }
    
    if (nextBytes is not null)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < nextBytes.Length; i++)
        {
            yield return nextBytes[i];
        }
    }

    // Introduce delay in case a write operation is going on
    await Task.Delay(200, cancellationToken);
}
```

But I still don't see a way to guarantee that each write will happen during the 200 millisecond delay.

Comment: reading one byte at a time is really inefficient.  The `Task.Delay` is pointless.  But the problem you describe is most likely caused by having several `ReadBytesAsync()` tasks running simultaneously and competing for the bytes.  As written, you can have only one, because even if the caller finds the end of the message he was looking for, this loop is still consuming bytes from `BaseStream`.

Comment: So if you want to use `async` you are likely better off using my original approach to read, and feeding data into an async Channel where my pattern called the `raiseAppSerialDataEvent` placeholder.

Comment: @BenVoigt thanks for the fast response, so you're recommending that I catch the received bytes inside a separate buffer and then propagate those buffer bytes through a method similar to what I've written above right (so that I can still use IAsyncEnumerable)?

Comment: I must also admit that I've never really seen an IAsyncResult before, or worked extensively with delegates, so I'm having trouble figuring out what your code is doing exactly (beside the receiving and copying of the bytes) and how I could fit this into a primarily async codebase.

Comment: I'm suggesting to use Channels instead of `IAsyncEnumerable`.  Your edit is not at all what I was suggesting.  The issue is that you can have only one reader, so pairing up received messages which are responses to outgoing commands with the `async` code sending those commands has to be done without calling the reading function multiple times. `IAsyncEnumerable` is bad for that.  In code I work with, I usually end up with a `ConcurrentDictionary<someKey, TaskCompletionSource<Response>>` that sending code adds to just before transmitting the request, and the reading thread pulls from

Comment: @BenVoigt Apologies, my edit wasn't meant to reflect what you were suggesting, I added it to the answer because the approach ended up working out (so far). In my current code the `ReadBytesAsync()` has the read loop followed by a write loop, and only one `ReadBytesAsync()` call is active at a time. However, I will look into the channels approach since I imagine that would be more robust, right?